# Embed nicely formatted \listfiles into document

Tags: metadata

I am preparing a document for my university and need to insert a list of used packages and their corresponding versions/dates in the appendix of the document.

One possibility is to just copy the output of `\listfiles` from the logs and format it by hand before actually handing in the final version of the document. But that feels error prone...

So is there a way to include such a list, table or whatever automagically?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The macros I propose just show the information for the document class and the packages, so only those with extension `.cls` or `.sty`, discarding the other files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\listfiles % initialize
\AtEndDocument{\printfilelist}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printfilelist}{}
 {
  \cleardoublepage
  \section*{Used ~ packages}
  \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{longtable}{@{} >{\ttfamily}l >{\raggedright}p{.6\textwidth} @{}}
  \nobbz_print_filelist:
  \end{longtable}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_nobbz_filelist_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nobbz_print_filelist:
 {
  \clist_map_inline:cn { @filelist }
   {
    \nobbz_print_fileinfo:n { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_nobbz_filelist_body_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nobbz_print_fileinfo:n #1
 {
  \regex_match:nnT { \.(sty|cls)\Z } { #1 }
   {
    \nobbz_print_pkginfo:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nobbz_print_pkginfo:n #1
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_nobbz_filelist_body_tl
   {
    \exp_not:n { #1 }
    &
    \exp_not:v { ver@#1 }
    \exp_not:N \tabularnewline
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variation for separating the file date from the information:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}

\listfiles % initialize
\AtEndDocument{\printfilelist}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printfilelist}{}
 {
  \cleardoublepage
  \section*{Used ~ packages}
  \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{longtable}{@{} >{\ttfamily}l l >{\raggedright}p{.6\textwidth} @{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\bfseries File~name} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Date} &
    \bfseries File~info
  \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  \nobbz_print_filelist:
  \end{longtable}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_nobbz_filelist_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l_nobbz_fileinfo_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nobbz_print_filelist:
 {
  \clist_map_inline:cn { @filelist }
   {
    \nobbz_print_fileinfo:n { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_nobbz_filelist_body_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nobbz_print_fileinfo:n #1
 {
  \regex_match:nnT { \.(sty|cls)\Z } { #1 }
   {
    \nobbz_print_pkginfo:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \nobbz_print_pkginfo:n #1
 {
  \tl_set_eq:Nc \l_nobbz_fileinfo_tl { ver@#1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_nobbz_fileinfo_tl { & } { \& }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_nobbz_fileinfo_tl { ~ } { & }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_nobbz_filelist_body_tl
   {
    \exp_not:n { #1 }
    &
    \exp_not:V \l_nobbz_fileinfo_tl
    \exp_not:N \tabularnewline
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution lists all dependencies. Is there a way to get only those that are explicitly included in the document's `\usepackage` statement? cc @touhami

Comment: @Erwann Short answer: no. One might think to patch `\usepackage`.

Comment: The solution should be updated with the solution of question                      https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479650/l3regex-sty-not-found                      replace                                                        \usepackage{xparse,l3regex,longtable,array,booktabs}                                              by                                                                                                               \usepackage{xparse,longtable,array,booktabs}                                                        then the solution works.

Comment: @c05772 Yes, thanks! Done.

Comment: @c05772 What kind of error?

Comment: Using the second solution on a very large document (638 pages) I get an error at the last line when compiling: _Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. \printfilelist_ But the pdf is created and the list (3.5 pages) appended, correctly, at the end of the document. I wonder if the extra tab is not coming from the fact that some packages have no date and/or no file info or something non standard (e.g. package yfonts.sty)

Comment: I confirm that if you add the line _\usepackage{yfonts}_ to the solution, it fails (but you can have the pdf with a return..) so this package is the culprit :-( and of course, if you check the file list you find _yfonts.sty    2019/04/04 v1.4 (WaS&NP)_ !

Comment: @c05772 I added a protection against this in the second implementation

Comment: @egreg, thanks, it works. I am just baffled by this type of bugs: in my youth I learned  with an example of similar bugs in a program having faithfully worked for more than 3 years, ... it was coming coming from a leap year (in COBOL!). This question is 8 years old, how could you imagine testing all the packages ?

Comment: @c05772 I didn't test all packages, of course. The package info was never meant to be pretty printed, I guess. An `&` in a console message has no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution

```
\documentclass{article}
%-- just for the example
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%------------------------
\newlength\mtl
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mtlistfiles}{%
\par\noindent
%%-- for measuring
\@for\@currname:=\@filelist\do{%
\setbox0=\hbox{\@currname}%
\ifdim\wd0>\mtl\relax\mtl=\wd0\fi}%
%%-- formating list
\@for\@currname:=\@filelist\do{%
\makebox[\mtl][l]{\@currname}
     \expandafter\ifx\csname ver@\@currname\endcsname\relax
     \else\@spaces\csname ver@\@currname\endcsname\fi
     \par\noindent}}
\makeatother
\listfiles
\begin{document}
bla bla
\mtlistfiles
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The example works but as above if you add the package yfonts, with the line _\usepackage{yfonts}_ (line 6 for example) it does not work anymore. The reason is that in the file info field _yfonts.sty 2019/04/04 v1.4 (WaS&NP)_ there is an ampersand &! This is a nice example of bugs for a programming course, how can you imagine that?