# Does \listfiles work on Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

I don't have my notebook available for some days, hence I was trying to answer to a TeX.SE question using Overleaf.

I've realized, unfortunately, that Overleaf hasn't the most recent release of the packages (for example, `biblatex`).

I would like to see the versions used, adding `\listfiles` at the top of my code but it doesn't work.

```
\listfiles 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\begin{document}
\just to create an error and get the log on Overleaf 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need an error in order for `\listfiles` doing its work.

Comment: @egreg I need an error to see the log on Overleaf (at least I don't know how to get it in another way :) )

Comment: A warning would also let you "open the log", so `\ref{foo}` ;-)

Comment: @LianTzeLim Yes, of course, what I mean is that you don't get the log on Overleaf if your code ends OK.

Comment: oh sorry. Perhaps this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265726/embed-nicely-formatted-listfiles-into-document

Comment: @LianTzeLim Your first suggestion (to create a warning) works, sorry for not having tested it carefully before, thank you! However, Torbjørn T. has posted a solution to get the log even if the code is without errors or warnings.

Comment: Overleaf should *always* allow to look at the log file: it contains ***essential*** information even if there are no warnings or errors. If it's not possible, then it's a big mistake on their part.

Comment: @egreg It's possible to get the log, see Torbjørn  T. answer, ciao!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Well, I don't consider downloading the whole project a real solution.

Comment: @egreg Actually, you're right, it is not very convenient!

Comment: (Overleaf co-founder here.) Thanks for the feedback! Agree that better log handling would be helpful. It's on our TODO list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a pain, but if you download a ZIP-file of the project, then you can choose *Input and Output files*. The `.log` file will be included in the ZIP when using that option.

[image]