# Missing FeynMF labels in TeXworks 0.6.6

Tags: diagrams, texworks, feynman, feynmf

I wrote the following code to depict a sum of two diagrams. I usually used only overleaf but given the dimension of the document I am writing I needed to download and use TeXworks. However, the aforementioned diagram, which worked on overleaf, now does not show any label. I red the entire guide for that package (feynmf) but still I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{feynmf}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{fmffile}{gzzexample4}
    \parbox{80pt}{\begin{fmfgraph*}(50,50)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1}
    \fmf{dashes}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{dashes}{v1,i2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,o1}
    \fmflabel{$\tau$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$\tau$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{$\tau$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$\tau_1$}{v1}
    \fmfv{decor.shape=square,d.size=3thick}{i1,i2,o1}
    \fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=empty,d.size=3thick}{v1}
    \end{fmfgraph*}}
    $+$\parbox{100pt}{\begin{fmfgraph*}(50,50)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1}
    \fmf{dashes}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{dashes}{v1,i2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,o1}
    \fmflabel{$\tau_1$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$\tau_1$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{$\tau_1$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$\tau$}{v1}
    \fmfv{decor.shape=square,d.size=3thick}{i1,i2,o1}
    \fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=empty,d.size=3thick}{v1}
    \end{fmfgraph*}}
    \end{fmffile}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: texworks is just the editor, what matters is the Tex system and package versions you have compared to the ones on overleaf.please edit the question to have a small complete test file not just a fragment

Comment: @Willoghby I reverted that edit previously  you have broken the code fragment adding a `\ ` at the end of the line, if you choose to edit to be a code block you need to remove the `\ ` markdown denoting a newline

Comment: I added all the packages that I am using

Comment: no I man the version numbers if you make an example with just the smallest number of packages that you need for th example removing all the extra ones that make debugging harder, then add `\listfiles` to your preamble and compare the list at the end of the log  package versions for thenon working installation

Comment: Ok I removed all the unimportant packages. But I don't understand what I should do with \listfiles, I am sorry

Comment: put `\listfiles` in the preamble then at the end of the log file (and terminal output) there will be a list of all packages used and their version numbers, by comparing the working and non working version you can see what changed see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342159/does-listfiles-work-on-overleaf